# Edit *.xlsx file (with Apache POI) and convert it to InputStream (without saving)

Tags: java, apache-poi, inputstream, xlsx, rest-assured

I got xlsx file. I need to read it with apache POI, then overwrite docProps/custom.xml, and finally pass as InputStream to RestAssured method.

Here's what I got right now:

```
        final OPCPackage opcPackage = OPCPackage.open(new File("C:\\Users\\UserXYZ\\Downloads\\1_upload.xlsx"));
        final PackagePartName partName = PackagingURIHelper.createPartName("/docProps/custom.xml");
        final PackagePart part = opcPackage.getPart(partName);
        final OutputStream outputStream = part.getOutputStream();
        outputStream.write(customParametrized.getBytes());
        outputStream.close();
        opcPackage.save(new File(outputFileName3));
```

As you can see I'm opening xlsx file then, overwriting /docProps/custom.xml inside file, then I save file and I could use it.
But what I need to have is instead of saving file, convert it to InputStream (without saving), and pass it to RestAssured method. So I'll could always open same file modify it on the fly and pass it to RestAssured.

Comment: Write into a `ByteArrayOutputStream` then turn that into a `ByteArrayInputStream`?

Comment: Ok, I could try that, but I'm not sure how to covert OPCPackage to ByteArrayOutputStream, any ideas how to do that?

Comment: In [OPCPackage.save(java.io.OutputStream outputStream)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/openxml4j/opc/OPCPackage.html#save-java.io.OutputStream-) the `outputStream`may be a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. `ByteArrayOutputStream` produces a `byte[]` array which can be used to construct a `ByteArrayInputStream`.